# Penalizing the solver from finding an optimal solution inside the cone of Second Order Conic constraint

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, second-order-cone-programming

Dears

We know that

X*Y>= D^2+T^2 is a second order conic constraint and it is convex.

However, it is there a way to make the solver understand that it is not optimal to find the optimal solution inside the cone and instead, it should find it on the surface of the cone?

Answer (score 2):

Adding any linear objective to the problem will place the solution at the border of feasibility (assuming you don't use an objective in an unbounded direction)

Comment: Thank you Johan for your reply. Would that mean that adding a penalty if X*Y became large to the objective function can help? I would appreciate if you may elaborate in a simple example

Comment: Adding $xy$ as objective would be a bad choice as you then wouldn't have a convex program any longer. Draw any convex feasible set on paper. Now try to go as far as possible in some direction while staying in the set (i.e. optimize a linear function $c^Tx$). You will then end up at the border of the convex set (unless the set is unbounded and you've chosen a direction which matches the unbounded direction).

Comment: If you already have an objective in your model, it is not clear what you want to achieve. The optimal solution is either on the border, and then you will get it, or it is in the interior, and then it would no longer be optimal to select some point on the border (unless you have a problem with a non-unique optimizer, where there are optimal solutions in both the interior and on the boundary. Is that your setup?)